# Need Advice in Javascript - New font family for every div

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm making a post site, but I'm trying to make each post have it's own individual font family.

You can see here with the cursive font, it is assigning it properly, but to all of a class.  I need to break each post into it's own individual iteration.

Since I am doing it on load, i can't seem to grab their Id's or Attributes easily and put them into an array.

my current solution is something like this, full code below
The randfontlist doesn't return a normal object, it returns something I've never seen before, like the entire post or something.
Does anyone have a smart solution to iterate through the

items with .randfont tag?
Thank you

```
randfontlist = $('.randfont').toArray()
randfont_idlist = $('.randfont').attr("id").toArray()
$(`.randfont`)[i].addClass(random)
```

[image]

**.html**

```
{% for poopfact in poopfacts %}
 <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <p>{{ poopfact.date }} </p>
          <p class="randfont randfont{{poopfact.id}}" id="{{poopfact.id}}">{{ poopfact.fact }}</p>
          <p> {{ poopfact.author }}</p>
        </div>
```

**.script**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
          
          $('.randfont').load(randomizeFonts()) 
          
          function randomizeFonts() {
            let fonts = ['caveat', 'indieflower', 'nanum', 'pacifico', 'pmarker', 'tangerine'];
            const randfonts = $('.randfont')
            for (let i = 0; i < randfonts.length; i++) {
              var random = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
              //get the ids of those items and put it into another array
              $(`.randfont`).addClass(random)
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming every font name in the `fonts` array has its equivalent CSS class to set the `font-family`...

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  const fonts = ['caveat', 'indieflower', 'nanum', 'pacifico', 'pmarker', 'tangerine'];
  
  $('.randfont').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).addClass(fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)])
  }) 
}
```

Comment: No. The suggested code is different. it uses an [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop on the collection of all `.randfont ` elements. So each is assigned a different random font class. -- Did you try my solution?

Comment: Ohhh i didn't see that one, I see it.  Wow man you're amazing!! Thank you

Comment: Happy coding and merry christmass! ;)